# uniform boundedness of derivativative

Tags: unbounded-operators

$X={f\in C(0,1): f^{\prime \prime }(t)<0}$.

$T:X\mapsto X$ is defined by:

$Tf(t) = at+ (1-t)\int_{0}^{t}sf(s)ds + t\int_{t}^{1}(1-s)f(s)ds$

and it is known that $\int_{0}^{1}s(1-s)f(s)ds < \infty$.

So that I have:

$|\frac{d}{dt}Tf(t)| < a + g(t)$.

where: $g(t) = \int_{0}^{t}sf(s)ds + \int_{t}^{1}(1-s)f(s)ds$

My instructor makes the following claim:

If we can show that g(t) is in $L^1$, then we have shown that $\frac{d}{dt}Tf(t)$ is uniformly bounded.

I have showed that indeed $g(t) \in L^1$.

But I do not know how this implies that the derivative is uniformly bounded

Comment: Would you mind to improve the formatting a little bit? What are $T$, $f$, $a$ and $g$ here?

Comment: Also, equicontinuity is a property of a family of functions, and any finite family of continuous functions is equicontinuous, so $\{T\}$ is equicontinous. See more at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity

Comment: Yes Guido Thanks. I failed to state that f is picked from C(0,1)

Comment: This question is unclear as stated. Please take the time to post a coherent, precise and clear question.

Comment: Thank you Zhw. I have it edited .

Comment: The question has been edited Claude Leibovici, Leucippus